# Initializing an array of structs (compiler error: initializer element is not constant)

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I am trying to initialize a C struct using the following code:

```
/* header file */

typedef struct _funky {
   int  func_id;  /* I know this should be intptr_t, but ignore for now ... */
   char func_name[MAX_FUNC_NAME_LEN];
} Funky;


double func1(double d1, double d2, double d3);
double func2(double d1, double d2, double d3);
double func3(double d1, double d2, double d3);
double func4(double d1, double d2, double d3);


/* .c file */
Funky fk[4] = {
                 {(int)func1, "func1"}, /* <- gcc barfs here ... */
                 {(int)func2, "func2"},
                 {(int)func3, "func3"},
                 {(int)func4, "func4"}
              };
```

When I attempt to compile this (gcc 4.6.3), I get the following errors:

```
error: initializer element is not constant
error: (near initializer for 'fk[0].func_id')
```

How I can fix this error?

**[[Edit]]**

After a brief chat with ouah, I have found the reason for this error - it is to do with the function definitions being used to initialize the array. Some of the definition are in different translation units, and others in different modules. All of which means (IIUC) that the functions will not be defined at compile time.

Short of writing an initialization function (which will require extensive mod in existing code) I'm not sure how to solve this - and I'm not sure how it compiled under previous versions of gcc either.

Comment: It shouldn't be an intptr_t, it should be a proper function pointer. Why ignore it since that's probably the core of your issue?

Comment: @Mat: That field in the struct is also used to store integers in parts of the code. I am working with legacy code and this struct is used in well over 5k files - sometimes the field stores an int, and other times, it holds a raw ptr. The best I can do is to change it to an intptr_t, this will require the least modification to the body of existing code.

Comment: An `intptr_t` is not guaranteed to be able to hold a function pointer value without loss of information, though it's likely to be able to. (Probably `uintptr_t` would make slightly more sense than `intptr_t`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson to add to this, if the implementation is POSIX it is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function definitions are not material to the problem.  The type used for `func_id` is, though.

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define MAX_FUNC_NAME_LEN  6

typedef uintptr_t ptr_t;

typedef struct Funky
{
   ptr_t  func_id;  /* I know this should be intptr_t, but ignore for now ... */
   char func_name[MAX_FUNC_NAME_LEN];
} Funky;

double func1(double d1, double d2, double d3);
double func2(double d1, double d2, double d3);
double func3(double d1, double d2, double d3);
double func4(double d1, double d2, double d3);

Funky fk[4] = {
                 {(ptr_t)func1, "func1"}, /* <- gcc barfs here ... */
                 {(ptr_t)func2, "func2"},
                 {(ptr_t)func3, "func3"},
                 {(ptr_t)func4, "func4"}
              };
```

As written, using `uintptr_t`, this compiles cleanly under GCC 4.8.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.4 (64-bit compilation).  Change the type of `ptr_t` to `int` and you get a pile of warnings.  The trouble is that the 64-bit address constants don't fit into a 32-bit `int`, so the loader would have to generate code to truncate the addresses, which makes them insufficiently constant.  With a 32-bit compilation, the code using `int` compiles cleanly too.

So, use a big enough type (`uintptr_t` recommended) and you will be OK.  The "I know it should be `intptr_t` but ignore for now" comment is the source of your trouble; don't ignore it.

Comment: +1 for honing in straight on the problem, and for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef _funky {
   int  func_id;  /* I know this should be intptr_t, but ignore for now ... */
   char func_name[MAX_FUNC_NAME_LEN];
} Funky;
```

there is a missing `struct` keyword here.

Also:

```
Funky fk[3] = {
                 {(int)func1, "func1"}, /* <- gcc barfs here ... */
                 {(int)func2, "func2"},
                 {(int)func3, "func3"},
                 {(int)func4, "func4"}
              };
```

You have `3` elements in your array but you initialize it with `4` initializers.

And as noted in the comments casting a function pointer to a `int` is probably a bad idea. There is absolutely no guarantee a function pointer value would fit in an `int` object.

Comment: My bad, I will correct the code I submitted. This is not the cause of the problem I am having though

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli did you see the last edit? I think this is the cause of your error message.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli ok, another edit on your original question. Are you sure macro `MAX_FUNC_NAME_LEN` is defined in your program, try to use some fixed value like `256` to test. Also please use some valid examples in your questions.

Comment: Yes, the constant is defined. Apologies for the previous mistakes in the sample code.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli OK so assuming the constant is an `int` greater or equal to `5`, your code snippet is valid and no conforming compiler could refuse it. Your actual program is probably slightly different. Your should create a single standalone test case which shows the failure.

Comment: I am able to replicate the same error by adding `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { return 0; }` to the code snippet above, saving it as test.c, and then compiling it with `gcc -o test test.c`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35873/discussion-between-homunculus-reticulli-and-ouah)